# Calling function pointer with variable arguments?

Tags: javascript

I want to do something like this:

```
function delegate(func, params) {
  func(params);
}

function foo(a, b) {
  // do stuff
}

function bar(x, y, z) {
  // do stuff
}

delegate(foo, 1, 2);
delegate(bar, 1, 2, 3);
```

I know delegate() will **not** do what I want as written.  How can I write a delegate() that would work for the above examples?

Comment: Look for documentation on `arguments`.

Comment: [MDN arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass all the arguments with [`.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments):

```
function delegate(func) {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return func.apply(this, args);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/8xkhrtg7/

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw my hat into the ring with an ES6 flavored example. I'm also using `bind` as opposed to `call` or `apply` in order to delay the function invocation.

```
function delegate(fn, ...args) {
  if (args.length !== fn.length) {
    console.log(`Warning, function ${fn.name} takes ${fn.length} arguments.`);
    return;
  }
  return fn.bind(null, args);
}

function foo(a, b) {
    console.log('foo invoked');
}

function bar(a, b, c) {
    console.log('bar invoked');
}

var whoops = delegate(foo, 1, 2, 3); // => 'Warning, function foo takes 2 arguments.'

var myFn1 = delegate(foo, 1, 2);
var myFn2 = delegate(bar, 1, 2, 3);

myFn1(); // => 'foo invoked'
myFn2(); // => 'bar invoked'
```

Comment: I knew somebody is going to make a ES6 answer for this question!

Comment: Haha, `[].slice.call(arguments, 1);` just asks for it. `...args` just looks so much better!

Answer (score 1):

In case you're still having trouble you can create the function like this:

```
function delegate(func) {
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); 

  return func.apply(null, args); 
}
```

That should do what you're looking for.

```
// Examples 
function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y; 
} 

function sumThree(x, y, z) {
  return x + y + z;
}

delegate(sum, 4, 5); 
//=> 9 
delegate(sumThree, 1, 2, 3); 
//=> 6
```